# How to set the section height to fit the screen?

Tags: html, css, height

Please look at this [website](http://aalulbaytisp.com/) , I use `section` for every page, as you can see by going to down to the second page there is some extra space that belongs to the first page(the following picture).

[image]

There are four section and every section height is set `100%`. then why there is an extra space there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The min-height for the body is set to 1000px to ensure that each block you can scroll to on the site has enough space to cover the viewport. So, if your height at 100% for one section is less than the 1000px minimum, then you'll end up with a huge space because the minimum is larger than what you really need.

You can optionally set height to an absolute value (x px where x < 1000) until the space is gone. Something like `#s1 { height: 700px; }` would work, where #s1 is the section you pointed to in your question, and 700px is an example of a height that would mostly remove that space, but leave enough in between sections 1 and 2. Feel free to modify that value until you're satisfied with the look.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is javascript. This is off the top of my head, and is general, but try something like this:

```
jQuery(function($){
$(window).bind("load, resize", function() {
    var sections = $("section");
    var height = $(window).height();

    height = $(window).height();
    $(sections).height(height);
});
```

});